# Set a gradient background color bug for UILabel

Tags: ios, uicolor, cagradientlayer

I have generated the gradient UIColor through the following code:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                     (__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,
                     (__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
gradientLayer.locations = @[@0.3, @0.5, @1.0];
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0);
gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(gradientLayer.bounds.size,NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[gradientLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *gradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIColor *gradientColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:gradientImage];
```

To verify the UIColor, I added the following code:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 300, 100)];
[view setBackgroundColor:gradientColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 240, 300, 100)];
[label setBackgroundColor:gradientColor];
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

I found that on the UIView, the color is normal, the UILabel, the color gets smaller[As shown:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN64V.jpg)

I wonder why? Is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I want to convert to UIColor, which is more flexible, for example, for setTextColor:

Comment: But that is not the question you asked.

Comment: Tested, UILabel in the use of all of the [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: gradientImage], will be smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of other ways to do this. `colorWithPatternImage` is always pretty skanky; why don't you use a CAGradientLayer? That's what it's for, after all. Or, since you know the view works the way you want, why not make the label's background color clear, and put the gradient view behind it?

Comment: Thanks, Your approach does solve the problem. I also want to know why direct [label setBackgroundColor: gradientColor]; The display will not be correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the problem is gone when using AutoLayout:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found that using frame, even if a normal UI image, UILabel would be misaligned. It has nothing to do with gradients.

Comment: I'm curious about how you do it. I use autolayout and still misplace

Comment: The autolayout layout will still be misaligned as the code creates UILabel

Comment: The constraints are in screenshot. So this problem is so strange.